# UINavigationController's interactivePopGestureRecognizer bug on iPhone 6 Plus in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios8, iphone-6-plus, interactivepopgesture

**This issue is only present on iPhone 6 Plus in landscape orientation**

If you have a `UINavigationController` and pushed a couple `UIViewController`s, the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` steals the swipe from anywhere on the screen.

The `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is only suppose to work if user swipes from the left edge of the screen.

This is especially problematic if you are displaying a `UIScrollView`, you cannot swipe the scroll view, because the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` will steal the swipe.

I have submitted a bug report to Apple. Any other ideas?

**Edit:**

Apple seems to have fixed this bug at some point.